# Attribute category not allowed on element li at this point

Tags: jquery, html, filtering, validation

I came across this [Grid/List layout demo](http://demo.webcodo.net/switch-products-view-grid-list-jquery-with-filter-and-cookie/) from this [page](http://www.webcodo.net/grid-list-view-with-jquery-category-filter-cookie-support/), which is pretty neat, but the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.webcodo.net%2Fswitch-products-view-grid-list-jquery-with-filter-and-cookie%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) gives this error for the category filter:

```
Attribute category not allowed on element li at this point.
```

Here's the filter markup:

```
<ul>
   <!-- change the "cat-1", "cat-2", "cat-3" with your "Categories ID" -->
     <li class="cat-active" category="prod-cnt">All</li>
     <li class="" category="cat-1">Category 1</li>
     <li class="" category="cat-2">Category 2</li>
     <li class="" category="cat-3">Category 3</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to fix this or use another attribute? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow @El Guapo's answer and change this line in the jQuery

```
var CategoryID = $(this).attr('category');
```

change to:

```
var CategoryID = $(this).data('category');
```

or:

```
var CategoryID = $(this).attr('data-category');
```

Comment: Please explain why this is necessary.

Comment: If he changes his attribute from "category" to "data-category" he must change the way he's finding the new attribute. He could also look for attr('data-category') but jQuery has a built-in for .data

Comment: he doesn't "have" to, and since he's dealing with strings anyway, there's no benefit to using .data instead of .attr.

Comment: I disagree, in your comment you say *"he must change the way he's finding the new attribute"* which is not correct.

Comment: It's correct to the extent that he has to change the attribute name. Let's not get bogged down with semantics. :-)

Comment: If he renames the attribute to "data-category" then he will have to change that line in the jQuery. I gave him a choice of options.

Answer (score 3):

Typically custom attributes (those not defined by the W3C) are prefixed with data-

so try: data-category=""